# VBA Command Button - Method or data member not found

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

having some trouble adding s command button to a user form. Basically, I want the button to insert data into a new row on sheet1 with the fields set as below. However when testing the button I get a 'Method or data member not found' error message.

Not great with VBA, tried reading online but I am still confused as to what to do. Please help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = ComboBox1.Text
ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = TextBox1.Text
ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = ComboBox2.Text
ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = CheckBox2.Text
ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = CheckBox1.Text
ws.Range("H" & LastRow).Value = ListBox1.Text
ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = ListBox2.Text
ws.Range("I" & LastRow).Value = TextBox2.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: You probably want the `Value` or `Caption` property, depending upon the control type.

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkboxes don't have a `Text` property. Use the `Value` property instead, e.g.:

```
ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = CheckBox2.Value
```

Note that this returns either "True" or "False". If you require anything else you need to do a check, for example:

```
ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = IIf(CheckBox2.Value,"Yes","No")
```